# Why is SSE vectorization not faster in this case?

Tags: c, optimization, mingw, sse

My SSE code is just as slow as the standard C one, what am I doing wrong ?

Im running on a Intel i3-6100 CPU, using C with minGW and CLion, im using the -O0 flag.

Im mesuring the performance using the clock() function, both versions are equally fast to about 45 ticks (of over 1000) (SSE:1138 ticks - C:1093ticks).
I thaught that SSE somehow messes up the clock() time mesuring, but even by simply counting seconds ther is no differnce.

the function : (swaping comments..)

```
void vTrace(struct Ray * ray, float t, struct Vec3f * r){
    //__m128 * mr = (__m128 *)r;
    //__m128 mt_m = _mm_set1_ps(t);
    //*mr = _mm_add_ps(*(__m128*)&ray->o, _mm_mul_ps(*(__m128*)&ray->d, mt_m));
    r->x = ray->o.x + ray->d.x*t;
    r->y = ray->o.y + ray->d.y*t;
    r->z = ray->o.z + ray->d.z*t;
```

}

the benchmarking code:

```
float benchmark_t = 1;
struct Ray benchmark_ray;
vInit3f(&benchmark_ray.o, 0.2, 0.23, 1.4);
vInit3f(&benchmark_ray.d, 0.2, 0.23, 1.4);
ticks = clock();
i = 0;
while(i < 1000000000 ){
    vTrace(&benchmark_ray, benchmark_t, &benchmark_ray.o);
    i ++;
}
printf("TIME : %i ticks\n", (clock()-ticks));
printVec("result", benchmark_ray.o);
```

the structures :

```
struct Vec3f{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float w;//just for SSE
};

struct Ray{
    struct Vec3f o;
    struct Vec3f d;
    struct Vec3f inverse_d;
};
```

Using SSE the performance should be about 4-times that fast why is there no performance gain ?

Comment: `_mm_add_ps(*(__m128*)&ray->o, _mm_mul_ps(*(__m128*)&ray->d, mt_m));` has some major strict aliasing issues.

Comment: how would I fix that ?

Comment: memcpy would be the naive solution, but you should probably use SSE types instead of structures.

Comment: Have you looked at the assembly the two versions produce?

Comment: I disassebled the C code and whyever it got autovectorized if I understand correctly...or at least its using the xmm0/xmm1 registers.

Comment: memcpy added a 20% performance overhead...in my case

Comment: Did you seriously compile with `-O0`? This essentially means "disable optimization". Try `-O2` or `-O3` (or maybe `-Os`) instead.

Comment: @JL2210 `__m128*` is like `char*` for aliasing rules: it's allowed to alias anything.  GCC defines it with `__attribute__((vector_size(16), may_alias)`

Comment: @noName: scalar math also uses SSE instructions like `addss` (scalar single) with XMM regs.  Seeing XMM regs tells you nothing about auto-vectorization.  Your scalar code leaves `.w` unmodified so GCC can't easily auto-vectorize.  And certainly won't with `-O0`, that's your problem.

Answer (score -2):

The code somehow autovectorized, I dont know why but it did.
So there was no great performance difference.
(next time step in the assembly code first)